# Can we enable syntax highlighting for code in comments?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, comments, syntax-highlighting

There is no syntax highlighting nor any ways to emphasize code written in comments.

I have noticed that this is one of the key factors leading users to misunderstand one another.

I use the backticks (`` `) and`%` signs at the moment for code that I write in comments.

**Please, give us an option to turn syntax highlighting on for comments.** We cannot avoid the fact that that some users decide to put code in their comments.

Comment: Comments are meant for shortish (note the 600 character limit) remarks on the question or answer. If you have code then add it to your question or answer - or post a new answer.

Comment: we might make bold and italic work, but that's about it.

Comment: @Jeff Atwood: Don't forget backticks along with bold and italic.

Comment: @Jeff: Thank you! Comments look now `awesome` :)

Comment: @Masi: Ironically, the new implementation just broke one of your comments: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/679108/which-quotes-does-a-programmer-need/679156#679156

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At least, I would want **bold** and *italic* to work.

As for syntax highlighting, you don't get that for simple `inlined code` sections, so why would you need it in comments.

Comment: If you mean that we should have inclined code sections in comments, then I support your idea.

Comment: Again inclined code in comments defeats the purpose of what a comment is for. There's a reason its character limited as well.

Comment: I actually think I would like the inlined code sections to work, as a highlighting feature.

Comment: @Brad Gilbert: I agree with you! That would be great.

Comment: **Hey** *look* at ***This***, `Code examples work too`.

Answer (score 5):

Comments aren't the proper place for full blown code. For one, it isn't even multi-line. Secondly there's no other way to format a comment.

If you have the need to post enough code that it requires syntax highlighting, then post it as an answer, or have the person requiring it ask another question where you can provide an answer there.

Comment: Or ask a question yourself and provide the answer to it.

Answer (score 3):

This is why you are supposed to edit your question or answer. Comments were just not meant for extended discussion.

Keep the comments short and simple please.

Comment: @Rich: I agree with you that comments should be short and simple. However, we cannot avoid that people put codes to comments. --- Therefore, I would like to have the code highlighting for comments optionally such that you can put it on if you have enough rep.

Comment: @Masi: We can avoid that by not encouraging the behavior. Code in comments is not acceptable (at least not enough where you would need highlighting), so why would we encourage this? Comments are less functional by design.

Comment: @Rich B: While I don't want full syntax highlighting in the comments, I wouldn't mind the ability to put stuff in backticks like in an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that atleast add support for a New Line. Presently, everything gets posted in one line. Its quite ugly.