# Text formatting now allowed in comments (List of proven and disproven abilities)

Tags: support, comments, markdown

What special formatting tricks can be done in the comments now?

**Proven**:

- `**text**` or `__text__` = Bolding = **text**
- `*text*` or `_text_` = Italics = *text*
- `text` = Code Formatting = `text`
- `[example](http://example.com "title")` Inline links with title and text
- `http://example.com` plain old links

**Disproven**:

- Cannot insert `<kbd>` (i.e. <kbd>F12</kbd>) characters
- Cannot use `#[text]` to increase size

Comment: [Really?](http://stackoverflow.com "Sweet!")

Comment: ___No bold italic.___ ([No links in parentheses](www.google.com))

Comment: Whoops! _If you put text before and after it, __you can do bold italic__ -- just not bold italic alone._

Comment: Multiple code lines work??

`string hexString = string.Format("{0:X}", -5); 
long hexValue = long.Parse(hexString, NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);`

Comment: +1 to VitalyB. Line breaks are important

Comment: And you can escape characters: \*this isn't italic\*, \*\*this isn't bold\*\*, \`this isn't codified\`.

Comment: Yeah guys, will you be adding multiple code lines in comments? That would be great since some times you need to edit/update the OP for add a piece of code

Comment: http://example.com

Comment: [link](http://example.com)

Answer (score 17):

click the help link under [add comment] to see a summary of the available formatting options.

[image: commenting help]

Comment: This is good, but might be clearer if there isn't a line break just after the `]` of `[link]`.

Comment: There is now even a "Learn more..." link to a [help page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) with more information (including some shorthand links not yet mentioned here).

Comment: @jeff-atwood does `@` work to notify commenters?... at least, if it does, for a while now there has been no link to the user's profile as it used to be before whatever change was made... also, there is no special styling to identify the person as, well, a person (as opposed to just characters after a `@`...)

Comment: @Richard, I'm writing this 8 years and 9 months after your comment, and the line break is **still there**!...

Answer (score 1):

The only bad thing is that it counts the markup toward the number of characters.  So bolding something means you can actually enter 4 characters less.  Of course, this effectively makes the minimum comment length 11.

Answer (score 0):

This is something that is only very recent - see http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001285.html for more info.

Answer (score 0):

This was new as of 2009-7-3, there is a comment by Jeff under this [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197/how-about-newlines-within-comments/452#452) which was posted on 2009-6-29:

> I would really like some of the basic markdown stuff be added, for example
>
> ```
> `code highlight`
> *italic*
> **bold**
> ***bold italic***
> ```

> hey look! *italic* and **bold** and some `escaped *code* sample` – Jeff Atwood♦

I also [mentioned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1149/to-put-syntax-highligthing-on-for-codes-in-comments/1241#1241) it on the 30th:

> At least, I would want **bold** and *italic* to work.
>
> As for syntax highlighting, you don't get that for simple `inlined` code sections, so why would you need it in comments.

Which means it had to have been implemented between 2009-6-30 and 2009-7-3.

Comment: ***bold and italic?***

Comment: `*`asterisk`*`     d

Answer (score 0):

This micro-ing of the MD format is annoying, because

- it does not allow
- the **list-bullets**,
- in the comments. :-/

Comment: If you want to put a bullet list in a comment, that means you don't know [what comments are for](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment)

Comment: "Leave constructive criticism" and "fundamental change" is exactly my point: The original answer had bullets, and to be 'constructive' and to show my point, I need bullets too.