# How do I use formatting in comments?

Tags: support, comments, markdown

I see some people write comments that are for example - in *italics*.

I do not see any way of doing that while writing my comments. Why is it so?

Answer (score 200, accepted):

```
*italics*
**bold**
***bold and italics***
`code`
[link text](url)
```

More details here: [Text Formatting Now Allowed In Comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2115/text-formatting-now-allowed-in-comments-list-of-proven-and-disproven-abilities)

<del>As for why the site doesn't tell you *how* to do this, I can't say.</del>
The site now has a ["help" link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) when writing a comment which tells you exactly what I have written above.

Comment: *italics* **bold** `code`

Comment: Don't forget [link text]( url )

Comment: @tim- added. [link text](http://www.google.com)

Comment: [It doesn't seem to work any more.](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/125637/what-is-the-ideal-shape-for-rail-gun?noredirect=1#comment251244_125637)

Comment: @TomášZato It seems that it doesn't work if you have a space before the final asterisk.  I don't know if this is a recent change, or if that has never worked. you can open an issue here if you want.  Ex: `*no space* *with space *` => *no space* *with space *

Comment: this doesn't work anymore, and this is a BAD thing !!!

Comment: @AlexMills What do you mean? seems to work fine for me: *italics* **bold** ***bolditalic*** `code` [link](http://google.com)

Comment: What about keypad keys?

Comment: If url conatins ( or ) its not working. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivity(android.content.Intent)

Comment: [.](http://www.stackoverflow.com)

Comment: `As for why the site doesn't tell you how to do this, I can't say.` [I disagree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yv56I.png).

Comment: @PrittBalagopal your screenshot is for writing an answer, not a comment. But help has been added to comments also at some point in the last eight years, so I updated my answer.

Answer (score 35):

Click the **Help** link under the button **Add comment** to see a summary of the available formatting options.

[image: commenting help]

Comment: Great solution as it will continue to be useful when things change!

Comment: I didn't even think to click on that because it's formatted as a link.  If I'm in the middle of typing out a comment and realize I want to add formatting the last thing I want to do is click something that looks like a link.  As I expect the default behavior of that would be to take me to another page.  It really should be formatted to look like something other than a link, or have a name other than "help" that indicates what it actually does.  Such as "show formatting options."  Or better yet provide the same editor that answers get with formatting options specific to comments.

Answer (score 14):

Use `*` `*` around your text for italics *like this*

Use `**` `**` around your text for bold **like this**

Use `***` `***` around your text for bold italics ***like this***.