# Formatting of comments?

Tags: support, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use formatting in comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24793/how-to-use-formatting-in-comments)

Is it possible to format the text of comments?

Comment: dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24793/how-to-use-formatting-in-comments