# Why can you type new lines in comments if they are never rendered?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comments, user-interface

In the comment box, you can type new lines, but they are never rendered.  This can trick people into thinking that they can separate text into paragraphs, when this is not possible.

I think that when the enter key is pressed, the comment should be submitted.

This would then be consistent with chat and asking a question.

Comment: A prompt before submission would make sense too, as users must be used to the current behavior.

Comment: As an aside: 

Newlines are served to the browser without first converting them to HTML line breaks, but browsers ignore newlines.

(See the source of this very comment.)

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63644/pressing-enter-in-comment-box-unexpectedly-submits-form

Comment: I curse you; this feature is very annoying. :P  I keep submitting incomplete comments by mistake. (E.g., this happens for me when especially when they're at the most incomplete: when I'm moving phrases around and used to use newlines to keep things uncluttered while I sort things out.)

Comment: @Shreevatsa, sorry.  I'm a big fan of the new feature.  I am about to use it right now!  Also, you can enter new lines using shift+enter.

Comment: @jinguy: This "feature" broke existing behaviour, differs from nearly every textarea on the web, has unexpected consequences, and violates the Principle of Least Astonishment. It makes it hard to do any nontrivial editing in the little box before submitting a comment; penalizing me with having to use Shift+Enter several times to save *one* Tab,Enter at the very end. See also the comments by Kop, deceze, and Henrik Erlandsson on [the other question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63644/pressing-enter-in-comment-box-unexpectedly-submits-form/64323#64323).

Comment: @Shreev,  I understand your frustration, but I'm not the person you need to appeal to.  I didn't realize how many people would hate this new feature.

Comment: I wasn't appealing to you; just reacting to your defence and admiration of this bug. :-)

Comment: -1 [Confirming context menu entries via Enter when entering comments triggers comment to be posted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66646/146482) - **edit** there, happened again when pasting the link...

Comment: This is a *dreadful* misfeature. What were you *thinking*?

Comment: @walky, I like it...sorry.

Comment: Ack. Now this lunacy has infected Facebook. I hold you personally responsible for breaking the internet! (Yes, I did see your Oatmeal.)

Comment: @walkytalky, sorry.  I hope you will forgive me sometime.

Comment: Very annoying "feature"

Comment: This works perfctly, the best is on android where you can hit enter without even moving the on-screen keyboard and trying to "touch" that tiny button (also nnote that there is no tab on the android keyboard so if changed back this needs to be addressed)

Comment: This is very annoying. On my keyboard the `'` key is right next to the Enter key, so it happens often that I accidentally submit an incomplete comment when I try to type `'`.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Comments can now be submitted by hitting <kbd>enter</kbd> while in the comment textarea.

Although newlines are not rendered, you can still insert one into the textarea by hitting <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd>.

Let us know if you find any issues with this new functionality.

Comment: Testing the new functionality. *(Cool!)*

Comment: IMO this should be reversed, or `shift+enter` should be accounted for...a multi-line text box says "hey press enter, you're gonna love it"...if it matched other programs (even SO chat) in the `shift+enter` respect it'd be ok, but now it seems very broken, definitely thrown me off several times today.

Comment: I very much found issues, please see here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63644/pressing-enter-in-comment-box-unexpectedly-submits-form/64323#64323

Comment: -1 [Confirming context menu entries via Enter when entering comments triggers comment to be posted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66646/146482) - **edit** there, happened again when pasting the link...

Comment: `Shift+enter` has no effect after submitting the comment. How can you write readable code this way?

Comment: @Jarrod, "Tab-Enter" is the standard for submitting textbox/textareas. Not "Enter".

Answer (score 9):

They might show in the data dump, right? That might be used for different formatting.

And even when they are never rendered, I still find them useful every now and then, especially when including inline links to other questions that might have dots or question marks in their titles. Enlarging the edit box in my browser, and using new lines, makes things slightly easier to read. Like:

> See [How does the comment system and comments work?]([How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-does-the-comment-system-and-comments-work)) Or [How to use formatting in comments?]([How to use formatting in comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24793/how-to-use-formatting-in-comments)) (But that's just my opinion.)

Versus:

> See [How does the comment system and comments work?]([How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-does-the-comment-system-and-comments-work))
>
> Or [How to use formatting in comments?]([How to use formatting in comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24793/how-to-use-formatting-in-comments))
>
> (But that's just my opinion.)

Comment: suggestion: do not get too attached to this behavior, or learn to press SHIFT+ENTER

Comment: Aha hint noted, @Jeff, so I guess should quickly downvote this feature request, even though my downvote would only apply to the part *"when the enter key is pressed, the comment should be submitted"* -- which matches the behaviour for the Search, but is different from the behaviour when answering. But well, even comments have an edit option, so nothing bad can happen, really. ;-)

Comment: @Arjan, when typing up a question, if the tags field (the last field) has focus, and enter is pressed,the questions is submitted.  So, there is some precedence for this.

Comment: Well, switch to a better browser. `:p`

Comment: @Jeff Atwood: If we're going to use newlines several times while typing/editing a comment, and only going to submit it once, why should the rare and hard-to-reverse action (submitting) take precedence over the more useful one? It's not that much effort to hit Tab and Enter **just once**, while it's a lot of effort to hit Shift-Enter multiple times.

Comment: @jjnguy - That is not precedence. The tags field is a *textbox*, while the comment field and question field are *textareas*. They have completely different expected behaviors. When you hit Enter in a textbox, the form should be submitted. When you hit Enter in a textarea, it should break to a new line. This is the expected and understood behavior for these components on the web, and there is no good reason to break them.

Comment: I don't get it.  You can enter an "enter" using shift+enter in a comment box, but it won't display (render).  There are many reasons to include more than one idea in a comment and it is "normal" in English to make them separate lines or paragraphs.
I have no idea what a data dump is in this context or why I should care.

Comment: @Joe, [the data dumps make all content available](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/stack-overflow-creative-commons-data-dump/) for other usage. So even though *these* sites don't render them, some other (future) site might.

Answer (score 0):

You only want this because your own personal workflow style is to write short comments that need very little thought or editing.

Whereas the more contemplative of us want to write, think, rewrite a bit, check our work, add URLs etc.  On some platforms, especially mobile, the backspace and enter key are so close you hit one or the other by mistake *all the time*.

This is a "fail-deadly" configuration.  In exchange for a tiny bit of convenience for you, we are stuck with a great deal of "Aargh, damn it", thrown off our train of thought, and having to struggle back to "edit comment".

*To add insult to injury*, a 5-minute timer is now ticking.  No big deal to a drive-by like yourself, but us contemplative folks often are not able to finish our comment properly in those 5 minutes.  Now we must go through yet more rigmarole to copy our failed comment, paste it to a new comment, and delete the earlier comment shard.

**Even worse**, in those minutes, a person often comes along and replies to our comment shard - and lacking our full meaning, their comment is often redundant, unconstructive or rooted in a wrong inference - and now when we fix our comment, or delete the comment shard and place the fixed comment below, the comment thread makes *no sense whatsoever*.

So the detour you must make when "press enter to post" misfires is much, much worse than the detour you must make when you hit enter and it moves down a line or does nothing.  Hence, "fail deadly".

It also rewards and encourages flash/emotion/snark comments, and discourages thoughtful ones.  That alone makes it more suitable for places like Youtube comments, not here.

### Kill "Press enter to post"

Comment: If it takes you longer than 5 minutes to formulate a comment then it probably shouldn't be a comment

Comment: @Cai who are you, to judge how I contribute? Is SE only for the quick?

Comment: Your entire answer is judging how others contribute, in a tone far worse than my comment; my comment was not about who I am just about what comments are

Comment: @cai fair enough, but I am not telling others how they should write comments.

Comment: Rather than performing necromancy on a feature request that was implemented 7 years ago, you should post a [tag:feature-request] question of your own.

Comment: @ale [Done.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63644/pressing-enter-in-comment-box-unexpectedly-submits-form/64323#64323) Trouble is, as we a re seeing of late in politics, saying "[protest group] isn't credible because of [flaws in their method of expression]" tends not to be sincere and tends to lead to advice that's poorly considered.  E.g. opening a redundant feature request is not better.