# Area 51 users have to press "Add Comment" to add comments

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, area-51, user-interface

[As of early September](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63303/why-can-you-type-new-lines-in-comments-if-they-are-never-rendered), the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key submits comments on most sites. I know there was some grumbling about this functionality at first, which is normal for UI changes, but it seems like most people have gotten comfortable with it now. It still hasn't been carried over to Area 51, though. Is this intentional, or an oversight? I, for one, would like to be able to submit A51 comments with <kbd>Enter</kbd>, now that I'm used to the behavior.

Comment: @Arjan, thanks, I actually looked up that URL and forgot to put it in the post!

Comment: I remember having read somewhere that Area 51 is based on a frozen SE-2.0 version and does not receive the main branch updates (usually)

Comment: @Tobias, that is the reason, you're right. But I think it would be nice if they'd port this feature over.

Comment: @Popular Demand: apart from [some](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/63644/146482) [bugs](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66646/146482), yes...

Comment: @Tobias, interesting. But whether those bugs should be fixed -- they should -- is irrelevant to whether the behavior should be implemented at A51.

Comment: @pop true too, it would really be good if A51 received backports. Also e.g. the inbox

Comment: CONGRATULATIONS, POPULAR! YOUR REP IS NOW **OVER 8,000!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We pulled in the press-enter-to-submit-comment change, so the Area 51 comment form has the same behavior as the rest of the network now.

Comment: will you also backport the inbox?