# How can I add new line in a comment?

Tags: discussion, comments, edits

It seems that comment style does not allow us to have new line. Can I know why?

Comment: Why do you want to enter a new line?

Comment: @Kenny You say that as though the concept of wanting newlines in text is preposterous :)

Comment: @Michael: But it is. In comments even if you enter a 
new line 
it cannot be shown. See the answer by @Adam below.

Comment: @Kenny, it *can* be shown. Just not on these sites. Or, at least not when using a regular browser to view them. (A text-to-speech browser might even use it on these very sites?)

Comment: @Arjan:




Yeah,




good




way




to




annoy




those




people




not




using




a




regular




browser.

Comment: @KennyTM, how is it annoying? Are you the kind of person who jams all of your text together into a single paragraph?

Comment: you need this for the same reason you may want bullet points.

Comment: So how can we enter formatted, multiline code, then?

Answer (score 16):

You can create a new line in a comment by pressing Shift + Enter.

The new line is not shown on SO, but should be present in the data dumps.

See answers to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63303/why-can-you-type-new-lines-in-comments-if-they-are-never-rendered) for reference and further detail.

Comment: I know it is saved and my question is why it is not rendered on SO sites.

Comment: @bernie, But it is not rendered as such.

Comment: How can i do this on mobile?

Comment: you save my day

Comment: test
it workss really !!

Comment: **Not anymore**.  Just tried it today (1/29/21) on a StackOverflow question.  Probably an artifact of the switch to a new rendering engine.  Hope it gets fixed ;-)

Comment: @TomHundt: thanks for testing and your comment. I have edited the answer to mention this change.

Comment: @TomHundt Looks like it works now.