# How to add line returns to comments in Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, markdown

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How about newlines within comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197/how-about-newlines-within-comments)
>   [Allow HTML tags in comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6407/allow-html-tags-in-comments)
>   [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work)
>   [Comments don't have formatting tags or line breaks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50444/stack-overflow-comments-dont-have-formatting-tags-or-line-breaks)
>   [Code in comment is all on one line](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88018/code-in-comment-is-all-on-one-line)
>   [Can you put code snippets in comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92332/can-you-put-code-snippets-in-comments)
>   [Why can you type new lines in comments if they are never rendered?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63303/why-can-you-type-new-lines-in-comments-if-they-are-never-rendered)
>   [How can I add new line in a comment?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67885/how-can-i-add-new-line-in-a-comment)

I want to add multiline code to my Stack Overflow comments but Stack Overflow parses everything to one line. I tried the two spaces

below is the code

```
            Set objApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
            objApp.Visible = True
            Set wb = objApp.Workbooks.Open("template.xls", True, False)
            wb.Sheets(1).Rows(3).Delete
            wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value = title

            objApp.Cells.Select
            objApp.Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
            objApp.Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
            With objApp.Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
                .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                .ColorIndex = 0
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .Weight = xlThin
            End With
```

Comment: No.  And I think you should lurk 'round here for a bit.  Posting meta questions on SO is a common mistake for NKOTB.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are wanting to add code into a comment then you are doing it wrong.

You should be either editing it into your question/answer or posting it as an answer.

Comments are designed for someone to ask the post owner for clarification. The post owner should then **update their post** with the requested information. You could then reply to the comment saying you've made the update just to make sure they see it.

Answer (score 2):

Not possible. Comments are all one lines only.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use Pastebin or put it in a question edit or answer. You cannot have multi-line code in a comment.