# Should the "Enable keyboard shortcuts" user setting disable ALL custom keyboard shortcuts on a site?

Tags: feature-request, comments, editor, keyboard-shortcuts

Since July 2009 the community is [asking for a way to disable the editor keyboard shortcuts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2980/578924).
Since September 2010 many people are [asking to disable comment submitting on Enter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/63644/578924).
Since July 2014 [navigational keyboard shortcuts had been added to the sites along with a user setting to disable them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/237166/578924), but the features requested above are still not implemented.

Like many other people I accidentally submitted a comment multiple times, because the input field is multi-line and I may reflexively hit the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key when it becomes more or less complex. I have the "Enable keyboard shortcuts" setting **disabled**, but the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key still acts as the <kbd>Add comment</kbd> button. I pretty much consider this a keyboard shortcut.

When I disable the "Enable keyboard shortcuts" user setting I expect **all** custom keyboard shortcuts on a site to be disabled!

I know there are [user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/123256/578924) [scripts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71837/578924) for the requests above, but there's also the related user *setting* which doesn't work as expected.

---

**Turning off the "Enable keyboard shortcuts" user setting should disable the following:**

1. Navigational keyboard shortcuts;
2. Editor keyboard shortcuts;
3. Submitting a post edit on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>;
4. Submitting a comment on <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
   The <kbd>Enter</kbd> key may [do nothing or add a space instead](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/176570) of a new line (i.e. what a new line would look like after posting a comment). I don't see much bad in key doing nothing, I think it's quite obvious that it has been disabled intentionally and just tells a user to leave this key *alone*, but you may [show a message if you believe it is needed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/172727);
5. **[Optionally]** Submitting a new question / post edit using (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+)<kbd>Enter</kbd> in a single-line field.
   Now, this is a HTML standard, it works everywhere and it may indeed be appropriate if a form contains *only single-line* fields. However, in forms with a multi-line field it causes inconsistency: pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> in a single-line field submits a form while in a multi-line field it adds a new line; this is why I propose to disable this.
   For consistency, however, it would be better to replace submitting on <kbd>Enter</kbd> with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> for such forms, which this setting would then disable altogether.

This feature request won't change anything by default for most users, but will allow people to disable things they don't like/need, while still preventing new users from trying to use paragraphs in comments (you still *can* add a new line with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> [if you know what you're doing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/63508/578924)).