# How to highlight comments in stackoverflow

Tags: support, stack-overflow, comments, syntax-highlighting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use formatting in comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24793/how-to-use-formatting-in-comments)

Its being more than a month since I started using Stack Overflow, and yet I haven't figured out how to highlight words on the comments that I make on the questions. Can somebody tell me how to do that?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I mean in this comments that i am writing right here. How do i highlight any of this words i am just typing?

Comment: Do you mean **like this** or *like this* or `like this`?

Comment: Or maybe `like this`?

Comment: Yes that is what i mean :) how can i do that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Do you mean highlighting `like this`?

If so, use the backtick - enclose the desired words, thus `word` becomes `word`.

You can also use 3 back ticks to enclose your whole code

```
#This is some code 
df=df['data'] + df['set']
```

Comment: Yes yes :) How??

Comment: @sfrj: http://img99.imageshack.us/img99/9948/graveaccentkey.jpg

Answer (score 5):

To highlight words `like this`, use backticks: `like this`

To *italicize* words, use asterisks: *like this*

To **bold** words, use double asterisks: **like this**

Comment: `Testing if it works`

Comment: Did it work i cant really see?

Comment: Oh yes it did :) sorry  Thank you very much now i know.

Comment: backticks are not for highlighting words. They are meant for code formatting, and IMO using them to highlight words is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Syntax highlighting is not applied to code blocks in comments, so there's no way to do this at this time.

Comment: good to know that :) But i dont need to highlight code, just sencences or words like this that i am writing right now.

Comment: How is syntax highlighting done in an answer(it is not there in the formatting help section of help center)