# how to post html in a comment

Tags: support, comments, markdown, design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use formatting in comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24793/how-to-use-formatting-in-comments)

How do I post html/css/javascript in a comment so that it's formatted nicely and has a gray background?

I'm trying to reply to a user and show them what i've done in a little snippet of code.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting. The only HTML that comments can support are `code samples`,_italic_ and **bold** text, and links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can format inline code with surrounding backticks.

For example,  `` `<html>` `` renders as `<html>`