# Is it possible to use superscript/subscript in comments?

Tags: support, comments, markdown

EDIT: this question is not covered [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24793/how-to-use-formatting-in-comments) as this does not refer to subscript or superscript

QUESTION:

How do I use subscript or superscript in comments?

`<sup>` and `</sup>` don't work.

I see the chemists using latex in comments [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/31587/are-there-any-known-chemical-properties-of-tritium-water-that-make-it-unusually)?  Maybe that's the only way?

Comment: LaTeX is the only way I reckon, among using Unicode chars. I'm interested to see if there's something else to it.

Comment: not a dupe, sub and sup not covered in linked thread

Comment: neither is latex.  Please remove this tag.

Comment: Which means, there's no way to do it other than cheats.

Comment: Yes it is covered, since it clearly says comments support only italics, bold, and inline code. That means nothing else in markdown is supported, including superscript and subscript. I guess someone can write answer "No" but think it's pointless.

Comment: Except that I checked that thread, and it has no mention of what I saw.  Which suggests to me the linked thread is out of date or just missing information on LaTeX (if that is indeed what's always going on on chemistry.stackexchange).  Is that a possible workaround on all stackexchange sites; are there other options?

Comment: Latex or MathJax or whatever only works on sites where it works (principally scientific sites). It wouldn't work on English, for example.

Comment: Well, `<sup>` and `</sup>` work for me Lᵒᵖmˢ wᵒw!