# Answer comment cells need text formatting

Tags: bug, comments, ios-app, code-formatting

I noticed certain keywords for text formatting are ignored in the app, e.g. code tags

See attached image for reference.

[image: see code text in my own comment on the question]

- App Version: 1.6.6.2
- Device: iPhone 7 Plus
- OS Version: Version 13.3.1 (Build 17D50)

Answer (score 2):

This is not a problem with the app (which, FYI, is [no longer in development](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342028/295232)); it's a problem with the content of [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55808975/unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-when-trying-to-pass-nsdictionary-from-swi/55851353#comment98289152_55808975). [Comments don't support HTML](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/24793/295232), if you need a code block there, use backticks (`` ` ``.) On the website, it looks the same:

[image]

Comment: Okay! Thought id point it out, should’ve checked on the web I guess. Thanks!