# Format code in comments

Tags: feature-request, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Text Formatting Now Allowed In Comments (List of Proven and Disproven Abilities)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2115/text-formatting-now-allowed-in-comments-list-of-proven-and-disproven-abilities)

Hi

I cannot format my code in comments (greyed out background, color coding etc), nor can I put in line breaks; is this deliberate?

Comment: Look at this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2115/text-formatting-now-allowed-in-comments-list-of-proven-and-disproven-abilities

Answer (score 5):

Comments don't have the same formatting - they are designed to be lightweight, after all, and don't have an editor etc. You can still use backticks `like this`, but just like inline code in an answer, there is no colour coding, just a `fixed width font`.

Perhaps add an answer (or update your question)?

Comment: which appears `like this`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Marc - yes, I do add an answer or update the qs - usually, the flow for me goes like this - I post some code, someone answers with a suggestion like "use this function", I say "it doesn't compile" and then I want to post the code that wouldn't compile - I can't put it in comments... which the logical place for that - I can only "answer" my own question with the code and ask for further explanation on that... o

Comment: or update the existing question and say in the comments section "please see above where I have written "Update code here <today's date>" - and this can go on and on.... I CAN work around this.. but seeing how fab StackOverflow is (really) in terms of the user experience I think it would help if there could be a richer comment section...