# Why do some user signatures appear greyed out?

Tags: support, user-interface, users

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the significance of a mostly blank user card?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89301/what-is-the-significance-of-a-mostly-blank-user-card)

Does it simply mean that the account has been deleted/banned?

[Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34121/format-code-in-comments) is an example.

[image: Greyed out signature]

Comment: Or the post was migrated from another site and the user doesn't have an account on this site.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It means the user does not (yet) have a profile on the site.  I believe this could be the case for one of two* reasons:

- User account has been closed (by user or moderator), or
- Question was migrated from other site, but user has no account on this site.

<sup>*)</sup> List may not be exhaustive.

Answer (score 2):

It means that the user has no profile on this site.