# Code block in comment not working when first character is a whitespace

Tags: bug, comments, code-formatting

I just added a comment for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23102895/how-to-remove-only-some-spaces-from-string/23102928#comment35314073_23103029) when I found there is something going wrong in recognizing code blocks in comments (the same thing seems to work in questions and answers).

I entered this in the comment:

```
` (#\d+)`
```

Which came out as plain text instead of formatted code:

[image]

Comment: Testing: ` (#\d+)`, ` (#\d+)`. (First is space, second is Alt+#0160) I think it has something to do with the parser...

Comment: The regex expects a non-whitespace character immediately following the backtick...so if you need significant whitespace at the start of your inline code you're out of luck...

Comment: @rene: That seems a good analysis. Is this considered a bug or expected behavior?

Comment: It  * works* *like* that for all ** inline** **markup** [ you see]( http://www.google.nl) so I consider it [to be by design](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2115/text-formatting-now-allowed-in-comments-list-of-proven-and-disproven-abilities)

Comment: this is a test `​ code` `​ test`

Comment: workaround: use the [zero-width-space character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space). But I really don't see why yo need that.