# Add syntax highlighting and line breaks to comment formatting

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, comments, code

Hello

I would like to see changes in the comment section. Presently, we cannot start a new line. Everything gets posted in one line. Even the code looks horrible.

Also, to color the code in comments.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1149/to-put-syntax-highligthing-on-for-codes-in-comments

Comment: i second this (not able to 'up' this answer yet)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is limited Markdown allowed in the comments.

You can create bold using the `**[text]**`

You can create italic using the `*[text]*`

You can do inline code using the backticks "`" on either side of the text.

Comment: What about NewLine ?

Comment: There is no ability to post new lines in a comment. I would suspect that this is because it is a general idea to keep comments short, and not to post entire essays which would require line breaks in between. At times I would like to have a line break, but in the grand scheme of things I don't think it is anything to worry over.

Comment: testing, **bold** *italic* `var x = 123; \\code`

Comment: how do I mark inline code? what's the syntax?

Comment: I also would like newlines in comments.  Sometimes you post code snippets and they *need* newlines.  I can't see any valid reason to *not* have them.  If it makes someone's comments take up more space on the page, so what?  Just scroll down!

Comment: @Naeem surround your code snippet with backticks `

Comment: Just b'cos some moderators think so...Its too restrictive! Rules are Good if you can explain its purpose Satisfactorily.

Comment: Test comment: **[bold]** *[italic]* `foo bar(){ print "working; }`

Comment: How do you post inline code that contains an actual backtick character? I tried using double backticks and it just shows two backticks...

Comment: just add two spaces at the end of a line for newline.

Comment: this is a test..this is a test

Comment: this is a test .. this is a test

Comment: this is a test.   this is a test

Comment: this is a test  This is a test

Comment: this is a test.    this is

Comment: `this is a test`

Comment: `this is a *test*` **s** [Google](http://www.google.com)

Comment: this is a **test**

Comment: test... **bold**, *italic*, " marked "

Comment: I know how to **Bold** or *Italic* but i still dont understand how to highlight something in a comment ?

Answer (score 17):

please.. allow carriage returns in comments..
many times the answer is a piece of code..
the backtick is OK but spaces are merged and carriage returns are stripped.

Comment: if it is an **answer** it should be posted as an answer.

Comment: Jeff, what if you are critiquing an answer? see my comment on an answer in this question for a legitimate use of code in comments: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3114252/one-liner-to-check-whether-an-iterator-yields-at-least-one-element

Comment: I agree with @Zibri and @superjoe30, there is no effective way to critique an answer given the existing limitations on comments.

Comment: Yeah Sure .Its a necessity.Give the user the freedom, with only essential moderation.OSS Live Long !!!

Comment: A lot of people asking for Line breaks..

Comment: Please, add line breaks.  I've had to resort to multiple comments as a kludge to make the comment readable.

Answer (score 11):

I'd like to see the `[Foobar](http://www.example.com)` URL markdown in comments.

Comment: I'm for this too

Comment: FWIW, this is now allowed -- I've used it a number of times.

Comment: [This already exists](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4481/add-syntax-highlighting-and-line-breaks-to-comment-formatting/18306#18306) -< that was an example

Answer (score 4):

What about links that provide readable text instead of a long URL? Markdown has [support for this](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#link).

See what I just did there? Now can we do that in comments?

Comment: Instead we get something like: Markdown has [support for this](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#link)

Comment: this looks kind of silly now that these links *are* supported in comments ;-)

Answer (score 3):

The original request has 'status-declined' but was asking for coloring and such.  That might be overkill, but line breaks really should be supported.

Comment: What would you include in comments that would need line breaks? (Bearing in mind if you're posting complex code, a comment probably shouldn't be where you put it.)