# Why can't we have simple HTML in comments?

Tags: feature-request, comments, markdown, design

Why can't we have simple HTML in comments; or at least newlines and tabs?  I think it would be good if we had such functionality.

Comment: Comments do support simple formatting: *italic*, **bold** and `monospace font`. There's also automatic conversion of URLs to links: http://www.google.com/

Comment: Duplicate http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4481/apply-markup-code-in-comments

Comment: Why can we not have HTML in comments, why can we not have Windows 9, why can we not be sober

Answer (score 7):

IMHO, the basic formatting that's already available — `*`*italic*`*`, `**`**bold**`**` and `monospace` (using ` on either side) — is quite sufficient for comments.

Comment: I miss [this link syntax][1]. It keeps the comment "source code" nice and tidy.

Answer (score 4):

probably because comments are designed to be kept small and to the point.
as SO isn't a forum, if you need to write a detailed response, it probably is an answer?

Answer (score 3):

Click the help link under [add comment] to see a summary of the available formatting options. HTML is explicitly not supported, just a subset of markdown we call "Mini-Markdown".

[image: commenting help]