# Why and when is a semicolon added to a comment?

Tags: support, comments, markdown, design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [strange character replacement on SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83837/strange-character-replacement-on-so)

When I write a comment with an HTML `<a>` tag containing both `href=""` and `title=""` attributes, a semicolon is added after the concluding URL quote:

```
Test link: <a href="https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/106431" 
title="Why and when is a semicolon added to a comment?">
this MSO question</a>
```

becomes

```
Test link: <a href="https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/106431";  <---------
title="Why and when is a semicolon added to a comment?">
this MSO question</a>
```

The HTML source is:

```
<span class="comment-copy">
    Demonstration comment: &lt;a href="<a href="https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/106431&quot;">meta.stackoverflow.com/q/106431"</a>; 
    title="Why and when is a semicolon added to a comment?"&gt;
    this MSO question&lt;/a&gt;
</span>
```

I'm aware of the [mini-markdown syntax](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) for basic links of `[inline text](http://example.com)` to be used in titles.  I understand that ([and why](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12786/why-cant-we-have-simple-html-in-comments)) HTML markup isn't supported in comments.  I won't actually type the above comment, and if I do, I'll fix it.

However, I still want to know in what other cases I can expect a semicolon to be added.

Comment: Demonstration comment: <a href="http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/106431" 
    title="Why and when is a semicolon added to a comment?">
    this MSO question</a>

Comment: [status-repro]. Note that the semicolon isn't actually added to the comment body, as you can verify by editing your comment (within the 5-minute edit window). It's only displayed. Weird.