# <br> Not Working Properly In A Comment

Tags: support, comments

I was trying to see why a comment looked like this when writing a comment with `<br>`:

> Any news on my answer? `<br>` I hope it is ***helpful***

Yep, when typing in the raw data for the comment:

> Any news on my answer? `<br>` I hope it is `***`helpful`***`

That comes the first comment shown. Strangely, using `***`helpful`***` will have the natural result of : ***helpful*** while the `<br>` will not be working. So instead of this:

> Any news on my answer? 
>  I hope it is ***helpful***

It shows:

> Any news on my answer? `<br>` I hope it is ***helpful***

Instead. Why is `<br>` not working when used in a comment? Is this intentional or a bug?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12786/why-cant-we-have-simple-html-in-comments

Comment: Whoa. The maybe-duplicate list that shows up when I write my question really needs to be updated a little better.