# <sup> superscript HTML tag has ceased to work correctly

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I have used the `<sup></sup>` HTML tags for exponentials and footnote numbers in SE posts for a few years now, and it worked as expected. For example, to render x^y, one can write:

`x<sup>y</sup>`

However, the past week (past few days?) I have noticed that they have ceased to work. They make the number smaller, but the raising of the number above the base line no longer happens:

> [image: <sup> tag not working]

Unfortunately, for obvious reasons, can not get a screen shot of how it used to look.

Why is this? Has there been a *recent* background change? Happens in Chrome and Opera (I've not tried anything else).

Comment: Tested on https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/296135/358759

Comment: Looks like CSS conflict, due to some recent change/fix/moving cheese around.

Comment: Seem to be SE network wide, in fact, in both "beta" and "graduated" sites.

Comment: [This Web Archived scifi question has a superscripts used throughout its answer.](https://web-beta.archive.org/web/20170106224601/http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/97166/why-are-there-so-many-47s/97168) That snapshot I've linked to is from January this year. It didn't used to have a vertical-align property set.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

We've been updating some CSS and seems like we missed there something. Fix is in repo waiting for build. Give it couple hours please. And sorry for that issue!

Comment: [x<sup>y</sup> doesn't seem to render correctly in comments!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61447320/recursive-function-c-program)

Comment: @bobobobo I don't think html in comments ever worked.

Comment: ['sup with that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12786/why-cant-we-have-simple-html-in-comments)

Comment: __markdown__ does work <b>but not html</b>

Answer (score 13):

This might possibly help developers to fix things a bit faster, please look at the bottom-right corner of this image, the `sup` selector has the `vertical-align` property valued to`baseline`. Unchecking the box in Firefox's developer tools brings back things to normal.

[image]