# How are users supposed to discover comment markup?

Tags: support, status-completed, comments, markdown

[Add syntax highlighting and line breaks to comment formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4481/apply-markup-code-in-comments) explains that limited inline markup is supported in comments. This is useful, and the limitation makes sense. However it's hard to discover what markup you're allowed to use: if you're used to saying `<code>`, you might not realize you need `` ` `` in comments. There's no help shown when you add a comment, as far as I can see.

Comment: For me [this trick](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4481/apply-markup-code-in-comments/18306#18306) was the hardest to figure out.

Comment: Ya, it took me a bit of time to figure it out. A guide would be nice.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33578/can-we-have-a-markdown-help-button-for-comments

Answer (score 12, accepted):

click the help link under [add comment] to see a summary of the available formatting options.

[image: commenting help]

Answer (score 1):

There's always the [formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122).

You can play around with the questions / answers there and post comments to see what's allowed.

Comment: Sure, or you can add a comment, have it come out wrong, edit it, google to find one of the pages on meta describing what is allowed, come back and find you can no longer edit it.  It's not great.

Comment: @poolie - You can then delete that comment and make a new one... but yeah, a quickstart or guide would be great.