# How do I view, but not edit, the markup for any given comment on any given Stack Exchange site?

Tags: feature-request, markdown

I found a comment to a post on one of the Stack Exchange sites at:

*[How to assess accuracy of phone GPS in measuring distances?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30545/how-to-assess-accuracy-of-phone-gps-in-measuring-distances#comment58828_30545)*

I see some special formatting that they used in the comment:

[image: Annotated image of the comment]

Yes, I know I can find out the special notation via the [Help](https://stats.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) button that is provided when you post a comment. But new users won't know about that help button that only shows up when you post a comment. Instead, I desire to view (but not edit) the unrendered comment text syntax, so as to see their specific notation.

Is there a way to do that? If not, then: This is an enhancement request for a tiny "View" button or icon *right next to that comment* that, when pressed, would popup that particular comment's text in a tiny form that I can use the mouse to select the raw markup text and copy it out for reuse. It might be best to provide an Edit button even if the current user does not have editing privileges, but only prevent them from posting the edit, but still allow them to select and copy the text out of the editing form.

Other helpful answers that were not exactly what I was looking for:

1. *[How are users supposed to discover comment markup?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63286/how-are-users-supposed-to-discover-comment-markup)*
2. *[Can we have a markdown help button for comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33578/can-we-have-a-markdown-help-button-for-comments)*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's not Markdown formatting, that's **MathJax formatting**.

You can right-click the MathJax and choose Show Math As → TeX Commands to view the source.

[image]

This TeX is enclosed within dollar signs to be rendered with MathJax. For example, the <sub>[image]</sub> is written as $D-d_j$.

[Not all sites have MathJax enabled.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216606/which-stack-exchange-sites-use-mathjax) [Here's a quick tutorial on MathJax.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)