# Since when are URLs parsed inside an inline code block?

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, markdown-rendering, inline-code

I just ran across [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/18306) which had been flagged for a broken link to `example.com`...

```
I'd like to see the `[Foobar](http://www.example.com)` URL markdown in comments.
```

That's all it is. For some reason, the URL in that inline code block is being parsed into an *actual* URL. The extra closing parentheses on the end is causing it to get flagged as an invalid link. Why on Earth is it getting parsed at all?

> I'd like to see the `[Foobar](http://www.example.com)` URL markdown in comments.

It doesn't get parsed in the post preview as you're typing... and it's not getting parsed in this question's body either...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The actual question is *until when were* URLs parsed inside an inline code block. This looks like a typical case of "Markdown bug fixed once upon a time without baked content being regenerated", which I've now resolved with a dummy edit.

Comment: Nice addition of a space. ;P