# Edit Comment- Default post by pushing return key is annoying

Tags: feature-request, comments, comment-edits

Sounds trivial, I know. But you are working on the text of your comment. In a small space. So the natural reaction is to get  a new line by hitting the return key. **Wham**, your half completed comment is posted AND you have only 5 minutes to get it right. Up goes the heart rate. Would it not be more friendly to have only the <kbd>Add Comment</kbd> button do the posting?

Comment: See also: [Add syntax highlighting and line breaks to comment formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/4481)

Comment: Done it lots of times. No real biggie, as five minutes is plenty to finish a comment. If I'm particularly concerned about time (kettle boiling), I can always delete the comment (copying text first) and then start again with no pressure.

Comment: While you only have 5 minutes to edit the comment, there is no reason you can't delete the comment and start over if you think 5 minutes is enough

Answer (score 4):

Well...since comments can't transcend multiple lines, there's no real reason to hit the return key until you're done writing it.  And if you run out of time, there's nothing wrong with copying the comment you half-started, deleting it, and starting fresh.

It took me a while to figure this out too, but once you train yourself out of writing formatted paragraphs in a comment, then this isn't that much of an issue.

Further, I would also disagree since it's counter-intuitive; there are forms all over the internet that treat the return key as "submit".  why would we want to break that in the case of comments?  Answers, I can see (and totally agree with; otherwise it would really suck to write answers).

Comment: I disagree. There is no need to have shortcuts like that for posting comments. It's better to make people spend a few seconds more while posting their comments - gives more time to look again at what they're posting.

Comment: Again, I think it's more of an acquired reflex more than anything else.  If you now know that hitting return will submit your comment, **you should take some time to think about it.**  Then again, I'm not entirely sure why the whole delay is necessary - if the comment is particularly nefarious or poor, the user can delete it instantly and normal users aren't any the wiser.  If they elect *not* to delete it, then that's what flags are for.

Comment: Yes, it's a reflex thing but still it just comes natural after having trained my fingers at it for so long. Of course, I could always correct my half written comments but sometimes I got a reply before I did so. If the other person doesn't remove such a reply later, it creates a mess. Also, I just think having ability to press enter to post is just not necessary. This is not a chat.

Comment: No multiline textbox anywhere on the internet treats the return key as submit (besides SO comment boxes), so of course it's counter-intuitive.