# Code Formating in Comments

Tags: discussion, comments, code-formatting

How can I format the code in comments?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Text Formatting Now Allowed In Comments (List of Proven and Disproven Abilities)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2115/text-formatting-now-allowed-in-comments-list-of-proven-and-disproven-abilities)

Comment: agreed on the duplicate, however the simplicity of this question is refreshing. It's a clear question and answer for complete beginners (like I was until about 10 minutes ago). The question above is useful to take your knowledge further.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

click the help link under [add comment] to see a summary of the available formatting options.

[image: commenting help]

Comment: Not clicking the screenshot is an IQ test I failed.

Comment: In my >2 years here I've commented 2118 times and not once have I consciously noticed that button. I guess it looks too much like "cancel".

Comment: I havent noticed this in more than 8 years now! the joke is not on you buddy! @FabianRöling

Comment: I failed too and I clicked "Add Comment" button on the picture :(